# DJANGO Signal.disconnect - inconsistent results (really weird)

Tags: python, django, django-signals, django-2.1

I have a custom signal and there is a `classmethod` which updates some objects where I need this signal to be disconnected so changes are not synced to pipedrive because this method is used only by a view for webhooks.

```
@classmethod
def backsync_all_stages(cls):
    s = sync_object.disconnect(sync_object_receiver)
    stages_json = PipeDriveWrapper.get_all_stages()
    if stages_json.get('success'):
```

And there is a view which calls this method if request is `POST`:

```
def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    model_alias = data['meta']['object']
    Model = PipedriveSync.WEBHOOK_MODEL_MAP[model_alias]
    if Model == LeadStage:
        PipedriveSync.backsync_all_stages()
    ...
```

The problem is that sometimes it disconnects the signal and sometimes it doesn't. When I call `PipedriveSync.backsync_all_stages()` inside shell_plus, it works correctly.

But according to view - I see in debugger that in both cases, the method is called from the same view. I absolutely don't understand what is happening.

So I invoke the webhook and set breakpoint under the `disconnect` command so you can see it returns `True` and traceback.

So invoking the webhook and waiting...

[image]

You can clearly see that the method is called from view and that signal wasn't disconnected (returned `False`).

Meanwhile there was probably a couple of another posts since the webhook sends multiple requests. So I switch to `Thread-8` in debugger. There I see that signal was disconnected properly.

[image]

The traceback is the same so why it's once `True` and another time `False`? This problem causes cycling through Webhook -> Client -> Webhook -> Client....

I noticed that everytime I call this method through `shell_plus`, the signal is correctly disconnected.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Your mention of threads leads to the suspicion that this is a thread-safety issue. How exactly are you running Django? How are you starting those threads?

Comment: @DanielRoseman It's runserver in debug mode in Pycharm Configuration. The thread with True value was some special case, I think the most weird thing is that shell_plus disconnects signal and the view don't.